# Why GridSearchCV in scikit-learn spawn so many threads

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn, grid-search

Here is the `pstree` output of my current running GridSearch, I am curious to see what processes are going on, and there is something I cannot explain yet.

```
 ├─bash─┬─perl───20*[bash───python─┬─5*[python───31*[{python}]]]
 │      │                          └─11*[{python}]]
 │      └─tee
 └─bash───pstree
```

I removed stuff that is unrelated.Curly braces mean threads.

- The appearance of perl is because I used `parallel -j 20` to start my python jobs. As you can see, `20*` indeed shows there are 20 processes.
- A `bash` process before each of the python processes is due to activation of Anaconda virtual environment with `source activate venv`.
- Inside each python process, there are another 5 python processes (`5*`) spawned. This is because I specified `n_jobs=5` to `GridSearchCV`.

My understanding ends here.

**Question**: can anyone explain why are there another 11 python threads (`11*[{python}]`) along with grid search, and 31 python threads (`31*[{python}]`) spawned inside each of the 5 grid search jobs?

**Update**: added the code for calling `GridSearchCV`

```
Cs = 10 ** np.arange(-2, 2, 0.1)
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
clf = LogisticRegression()
gs = GridSearchCV(
    clf,
    param_grid={'C': Cs, 'penalty': ['l1'],
                'tol': [1e-10], 'solver': ['liblinear']},
    cv=skf,
    scoring='neg_log_loss',
    n_jobs=5,
    verbose=1,
    refit=True)
gs.fit(Xs, ys)
```

**Update (2017-09-27)**:

I wrapped up a [test code](https://gist.github.com/zyxue/b4d6837cf890f78cf818d0becc939ce8) on gist for you to easily reproduce if interested.

I tested the same code on a Mac Pro and multiple linux machines, and reproduced @igrinis' result, but only on the Mac Pro. On the linux machines, I get different numbers than before, but consistently. So the number of threads spawned may depend on the particular data feed to GridSearchCV.

```
python─┬─5*[python───31*[{python}]]
       └─3*[{python}]
```

Note that the pstree installed by homebrew/linuxbrew on Mac Pro and linux machines are different. Here I post the exact versions I used:

Mac:

```
pstree $Revision: 2.39 $ by Fred Hucht (C) 1993-2015
EMail: fred AT thp.uni-due.de
```

Linux:

```
pstree (PSmisc) 22.20
Copyright (C) 1993-2009 Werner Almesberger and Craig Small
```

The Mac version doesn't seem to have an option to show threads, which I thought could be why they are not seen in the result. I haven't found a way to inspect threads on Mac Pro easily yet. If you happen to know a way, please comment.

**Update (2017-10-12)**

In another set of experiment, I confirmed that setting the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` makes a difference.

Before `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`, there are many (63 in this case) threads without unclear use spawned as described above:

```
bash───python─┬─23*[python───63*[{python}]]
              └─3*[{python}]
```

No use of linux `parallel` here. `n_jobs=23`.

After `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`, no threads spawned, but the 3 Python processes are still there, whose use I am still unaware of.

```
bash───python─┬─23*[python]
              └─3*[{python}]
```

I initially came across `OMP_NUM_THREADS` because it causes error in some of my GridSearchCV jobs, error messages are something like this

```
OMP: Error #34: System unable to allocate necessary resources for OMP thread:
OMP: System error #11: Resource temporarily unavailable
OMP: Hint: Try decreasing the value of OMP_NUM_THREADS.
```

Comment: Can you show the function call with the exact parameter values for GridSearchCV ?

Comment: @MohammedKashif, please see my added code

Comment: ActivityMonitor shows the number of threads on Mac. 1 process had 4 threads, others 5 only 1.

Comment: set `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=1`, this may play a role

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `sklearn.GridSearchCV` doc:

> n_jobs : int, default=1
>   Number of jobs to run in parallel.
>
> pre_dispatch : int, or string, optional
>   Controls the number of jobs that get dispatched during parallel execution. Reducing this number can be useful to avoid an explosion of memory consumption when more jobs get dispatched than CPUs can process. This parameter can be:
>   None, in which case all the jobs are immediately created and spawned. Use this for lightweight and fast-running jobs, to avoid delays due to on-demand spawning of the jobs
>   An int, giving the exact number of total jobs that are spawned
>   A string, giving an expression as a function of n_jobs, as in ‘2*n_jobs’

If I understand documentation properly, the `GridSearchCV` spawns a bunch of threads as number of grid points, and only runs `n_jobs` simultaneously. Number 31 I believe is some kind of cap limit of your 40 possible values. Try to play with value of `pre_dispatch` parameter.

Another 11 threads I believe have nothing to do with the `GridSearchCV` itself, as it is shown on the same level. I think it is leftovers of other commands.

By the way, I don't observe such behavior on Mac (only see 5 processes spawn by the `GridSearchCV` as one would expect) so it may come from incompatible libraries. Try updating `sklearn` and `numpy` manually.

Here is my `pstree` output (part of the path deleted for privacy):

```
 └─┬= 00396 *** -fish
   └─┬= 21743 *** python /Users/***/scratch_5.py
     ├─── 21775 *** python /Users/***/scratch_5.py
     ├─── 21776 *** python /Users/***/scratch_5.py
     ├─── 21777 *** python /Users/***/scratch_5.py
     ├─── 21778 *** python /Users/***/scratch_5.py
     └─── 21779 *** python /Users/***/scratch_5.py
```

**answer to the second comment:**

That's your code actually. Just generated separable 1d two class problem:

```
N = 50000
Xs = np.concatenate( (np.random.random(N) , 3+np.random.random(N)) ).reshape(-1, 1)
ys = np.concatenate( (np.zeros(N), np.ones(N)) )
```

100k samples was enough to get CPU busy for about a minute.

Comment: Can you please show what your `pstree` output look like?

Comment: Can you please show your code , as well? I will try to reproduce your experiment

Comment: I reproduced your results on a Mac OS, but the exact same code I tested on multiple Linux machines still spawns many threads. I've posted my entire testing code on gist, pls see the updates.

Comment: could you please try the experiment on an linux machine and see how it goes?

Comment: Hi @igrinis, do you think you've figured out why. I tended to give you the bounty, but not sure if your results qualify as the answer yet.

Comment: I've looked at the source code. From what I saw, the parallelization in `LogisticRegression` is done by multiprocessing, because of GIL issues, unless the solver selected is `'sag'` (then it is more efficient to use multithreading). So, I come to conclusion that 31 threads you see are `python` interpreter helper threads, that are run internally for scheduling and data transfer purposes, so the workers will not starve. I believe that if you drill down on threads you will see that most of them sleep, because `python` really suck in multithreaded calculations (GIL stuff).